# "Studies of (subject)" vs. "Studies in (subject)"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

I am confused as to which one is correct:

> I would like to continue my studies **of** economics.
>
> I would like to continue my studies **in** economics.

Can anybody explain to me?

Answer (score 3):

"Studies" are normally *in* a field.  [It is so much more common to say **"studies in economics"** than anything else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his%20studies%20*%20economics&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Chis%20studies%20%2A%20economics%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhis%20studies%20in%20economics%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhis%20studies%20of%20economics%3B%2Cc0) that anything else sounds strange.

Comment: You might well continue your studies *of* stock market fluctuations *in* your final year economics degree. That's to say, of a specialisation in your field of interest.

Comment: But I think "I would like to continue my *study of* economics." would be OK. *study* being a mass noun to include all those activities that will make you an expert.

Comment: @user3169 - Good point.  Something is the study *of* economics, but you do studies *in* economics.  English is weird like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about "study" used as a noun, as in "Book X is a study of topic Y," then I quite agree that "of" is better than "on." I am not sure that "on" is necessarily out-and-out incorrect in these circumstances, it may be an established usage, but "of" sound a lot better to me.

Just to confuse matters, sometimes the noun "study" can take the proposition "in," as in the title of the Sherlock Holmes novel, "A Study in Scarlet."